# Putting the greatings count on top and then displaying the username

Tags: mysql, sql

I wanted to SELECT all from users and then display all outputs ASC but I want to display those whose have a higher COUNT on top ASC. Here is the code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM user 
        ORDER BY user_id ASC, 
                 (SELECT * 
                  FROM user 
                  WHERE count > 40 
                  ORDER BY hits DESC) DESC";
```

Basically SELECT all users and then display ORDER BY user_id ASC but I also want to put ORDER to those users who have higher counts on top first. What am I missing from this sql?

Comment: what is your table structures (field names)

Comment: `usernames:  Jamie, Jonie, Jones, Janes, Jolos, Jilos`

Comment: table structure plz no table data

Comment: `count: 0, 4, 5, 25, 42, 45`

Comment: table structure means that (user_name,user_id,count,... for example)-what is your table structure and field names ?

Comment: show table structures and sample input and output

Comment: Oh boy. We're going to be here a while :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE count > 40 ORDER BY count DESC, user_id ASC
```

Comment: No but I want the count separate.... not to segregate those from the count....so I want all my users displayed but only the ones with highest count on top.